# How to concatenate variavél no vs code with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm new to NodeJs and I'm using VS code with JavaScript. But he's not recognizing the contenation.

When I pass the route: http://localhost:3000/user/2 instead of returning 2 it returns: "message": "GET API ${id}"

```
const express = require('express')
const server = express()

server.get('/user/:id', (req, res) => {

const id = req.params.id

return res.json({message: 'GET API ${id}'}) ----my problema is here
})

server.listen(3000)
```

Comment: What is "variavél no vs code"? It seems the machine translator did not get that bit, perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use this character to cancat ` (backticks)

```
return res.json({message: `GET API ${id}`})
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.

Answer (score 0):

The line you pointed out should use backticks instead of single quotes - for example:

```
return res.json({message: `GET API ${id}`});
```

See here for more about string interpolation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals